# Help with multinomial logistic regression

Tags: logistic-regression, interpretation, ridge-regression

I am a data science student and have the opportunity to work on an article regrading cardiac arrests in our country. For now I performed the multinomial regression model and I also plan on doing a random forest. I was wondering if anyone could take the time to look at how I performed the multinomial regression analysis.

We are looking at features affecting the survival after cardiac arrest (CA). We chose multinomial instead of logistic model because possible outcomes are: survived, did not survive, unknown.

1. Features that were chosen were based on literature review by
   doctors. We talked about backward/forward feature selection but
   since we wanted to see the results for all the features that doctors
   deemed importat we went with a fixed feature set.
2. For categorical variables we used one-hot-encoding. Each categorical
   variable also has 'unknown' for a possible answer. For missing
   numerical variables (like response time) we used the mean of the variable.
   We didn't exclude any cases, no matter how many 'unknown' answers it
   had. Our dataset consists of around 200 cases.
3. We perfomerd LOOCV to obtain the optimal regularization parameter
   that minimizes mean log score after LOOCV. We report the mean log
   score, accuracy and RMSE after LOOCV. We made sure we standardized the numerical features before LOOCV
4. We obtain model coefficients and 95 % CI with bootstrap. We sample
   with replacement 1000 times. We plot the values of coefficients and
   their CI. We report the coefficients that we obtained for the outcome SURVIVED (and nothing for outcomes DID NOT SURVIVE or UNKNOWN).

My questions are also

- how to proceed with the interpretation? Since most of our variables are categorical we get very small coefficients (0.7 is the greatest) and the differences between them are very small. Can we really say one variable is more positively associated with survival if the difference between them is small (even if their CIs do not overlap)?
- is there any better way to report on the coefficients? I have seen many articles report "odds ratios" but I cannot find a clear explaination about how this is connected to coefficients

Thank you so much!

Comment: What would it mean to classify someone as *unknown*?

Comment: It happens when doctors have trouble obtaining info about a patient - for example they know the patient left the hospital alive but not if the patient survived at least 30 days after event (which is the survival we are measuring) and they were unable to trace the info at the time of data collection.

Comment: That really seems like missing data, not a third category. Do you really want to build a model that predicts patients as falling into the category where doctors won’t be able to collect the info? (Perhaps you have a compelling argument for why you want to, and I’d be interested in it, but I’m  not seeing it.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.